# How to figure out what kind of intent was thrown

Tags: android, android-intent, whatsapp

Is there any possibility to find out, which Intent some App is throwing?
For example if there is a new whatsapp message as notification to catch the message while klicking on the notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Logcat. All sent Intents are logged there.